# CoffeeOrder java task

Tags: java

Hey having issues with the java task.
What is required of the output is to print out whether or not the coffee is soy, how many shots of caffeine, and what kind of coffee it is.
If the amount of shots is 3 or greater then it is classed as Overly Intense

```
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 * Coffee Order Generator (4.1PP IFTTT)
 * 
 * @author Josh French
 */

public class CoffeeOrder {


    public static void main(String[] args) 
    { 
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String coffee; //user's description of kind of coffee
        String shots_String; //holds Single shot, Double shot, Overly Intense
        int shots; //number of coffee shots, 1, 2, possibly higher
        boolean withSoy; //use soy milk instead of regular milk?


        //Get coffee details from user
        System.out.print("What kind of coffee would you like (e.g., latte, cappuccino)? ");
        coffee = sc.nextLine(); //in case they say 'flat white'
        System.out.print("How many shots? ");
        shots = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.print("With soy milk (true or false)? ");
        withSoy = sc.nextBoolean();
        shots_String = sc.next();      


        if (shots == 1)
        {
             shots_String = "Single shot";
        }
        else if (shots == 2)
        {
            shots_String = "Double shot";
        }
        else if (shots >= 3)
        { 
           shots_String = "Overly Intense"; 
        }


        //Display order details
        System.out.print("Order details: ");
        System.out.print("  " + shots_String);
        System.out.print("  " + withSoy);
        System.out.print("  " + coffee);        
        System.out.println();
        }

 }
```

Comment: `shots_String = sc.next();` is going to wait until you enter something, not sure why you've got it, I would have thought maybe `nextLine` might be more useful

Comment: I'd change `String shots_String;` to `String shots_String = "";` and remove `shots_String = sc.next();`

Comment: Before i added the "shots_String = sc.next();" line in i kept on getting the error of it shots_String not being initialized.
Error: variable shots_String might not have been initialized

Comment: Thanks MadProgrammer that fixed it ^_^

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, _a specific problem or error_ and _the shortest code necessary_ to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).